# How do I show several webpages in PHP with sleep?

Tags: php, sleep

The following script waits 2 seconds and then displays the last htm only.

How can I get it to display the first page, then wait 2 seconds and then display the second?

```
<?php

header("Location: http://10.xxx.24.xx/holdingpage.htm");
sleep(2);
header("Location: http://10.xxx.24.xx/webpageTMMSTATE.htm");
die();

?>
```

I would also be happy to NOT display first page, but just print some text on page, then wait 2 secs before displaying next page.

Comment: That is not possible by means of server side scripting. You have to do that on the client side (so using javascript), and even then things are a little more complex, since you have to take care not to remove your own script when loading the next page...

Comment: @arkascha What about just print some text? See edit above

Comment: Same thing. The reason is simple: if you send the client away to another server by means of a location header, then you have no connection to the client any longer... The only thing possible like that is to forward the client to only _one_ subsequent page. But even that has to be done client sided. You simply cannot send an additional header when you already sent other output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the redirection logic out of PHP and into your HTML. In your holdingpage.htm for example:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;http://10.xxx.24.xx/webpageTMMSTATE.htm" />
etc...
</head>
```

This way when you load holdingpage.htm it will wait 2 seconds then make a request to refresh the page with the webpageTMMSTATE.htm.